# How to access or modify html values from mounted el?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

My Cable.vue contains html to render

```
    <template>
    <input id="number" />
...
    </template>
    ...
```

I've a rendered cable.vue  html document in another vuejs file home.vue.
I want to access `el` elements and modify values while rendering it, like I've tried to use  in home.vue

```
import Cable from 'cable.vue';
import { createApp } from 'vue'

const cableInstance = createApp(Cable)
const el = document.createElement('div')
cableInstance.mount(el)
//document.getElementById('number').value = 11
// this throws error , 'number' is null.
```

I also tried to use  `el` directly

```
el.getElementById('number').value = 11 // dont works either
```

Is there any way to modify elements while rendering documents.

Comment: This is XY problem. Vue isn't jQuery, it isn't supposed to be used like that. If these are your own components, you can make them able to communicate, one way or another. The problem here is that `el` is detached from DOM, it's unavailable in `document`.

Comment: how can i make them able to communicate one way or another would you please give me  hint, thank you

Comment: Most likely a common app that hosts both components. It's not obvious why they should be separate apps.

Comment: Hello Ectus thankyou for replying, I tried to make another element thinking to put inside that form in cable.vue file, but problem here was  cable.vue have <div> ..<form></form></div>    , using just el.appendChild(input_element) just append the input in div not inside that form, How can i push it inside of inside of the form. Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't use appendChild and other direct DOM access, unless you know you should. This isn't how Vue works. You need to use a hierarchy of components in order to have a hierarchy of DOM elements as the output. I can't say how exactly because the question doesn't contain enough info.

Comment: Hello Thank you so much for helping. I really appretiate.  I left that appending idea, 
I'm thinking to send a variable from that home.vue to cable.vue. Actually my problem was, that variable is changing everytime, and it is inside a specific function rather than mounted, I'm looking if how can i send that variable to that cable.vue. (I'm in form making, and i left idea to make hidden element rather just send the given data without rendering html through api. can you please help.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly is the relationship between home and cable. Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Generally Vue reactivity should be used to pass data between components.

Comment: thank you , i'm sorry if i made your time loss. I tried to use window.varname to make global variable, although it is not reactive and doesnt changes its data as i move things. 
I hope i would find the way

Comment: Hello @EstusFlask I've solved problem :) I've used store and used based on that, it is working properly now. Please remove my question,